# How do I see what channels are set up between parachains?

Tags: xcmp

How do I see what xcmp channels are set up between parachains on kusama and polkadot?

Answer (score 2):

There's a great visualisation of the kusama channels set up here:

https://dotsama-channels.vercel.app/#/

And if you wonder where to get the source data, you can query the following storage from Polkadot.js:

- `hrmp.hrmpChannels`: the opened channels
- `hrmp.hrmpOpenChannelRequests`: the pending open channel requests
- `hrmp.hrmpCloseChannelRequests`: the pending close channel requests